# Concerns regarding uninstalling packages

Tags: package

In order to uninstall a package from Emacs I read that I must delete the specific folder from the elpa folder. As the .emacs file is being written by itself when I install a package does that mean that it will also delete itself when I uninstall a package or I must delete specific entries by myself? Also I installed an auto complete package and inside elpa folder I found a folder with the name `popup-20141002.320`. Why was that folder in there? Can packages install other packages? If so then when I uninstall the first package I must uninstall also the one it installed by itself?

Comment: Installing packages via `package-install` *should not* alter your init file.  And yes, the package manager will install dependencies for packages you install. So `popup` is a dependency for `auto-complete`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you uninstall a package, it is deleted for you. This is actually the entirety of the uninstall operation (see the `package-delete` function). Deletion can also be done manually by removing it from the installation directory (defaulting to `.emacs.d/elpa/` for user-installed packages). This manual deletion does *not* have any adverse side-effects on the package-management system, which simplifies recovery should things go wrong.

Packages may depend on other packages in order to function properly. These *dependencies* are automatically installed when you install a package through the built-in package manager (`package.el`). If you are using `M-x package-list-packages` to view available packages, then you can see what packages will be installed (if they are not present) by pressing `RET` or clicking on a package name.

Uninstalling a package through the interface does *not* remove dependencies. This information is not documented ăs far as I can tell. You can see for yourself by reading through the `package-menu-execute` and `package-delete` functions or by installing a package with a dependency that you do not have installed, then removing the main package and observing the dependency's status.

*Update* Since emacs 25.1 there is a command `package-autoremove` that deletes packages no longer needed because they were only installed as a dependency of deleted package.  If you delete an installed package from the package list, then emacs pops up a suggestion to run this command when appropriate.

Comment: Also I wouldn't try to delete the dependency packages as more than one package might be depending on them, not just the one you are trying to delete.

Comment: Any symbols loaded into Emacs appear to remain in Emacs until you restart Emacs…